# High traffic hosting provider

Tags: networking, hosting, bandwidth

Currently I found myself in very interesting position.
I had to build a server that is capable of serving around 100TB per month.
The server config and the software is not an issue for me, but the network cost of 100TB per month make my usual choice of AWS EC2 to look ugly to the end client. :(

On top of it the traffic destination is India, so the servers has to be located in Asia - preferably.

Please advice on the best practice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check akamai , they have one of the biggest cdn networks and colaborate with all the large isp's.

http://www.akamai.com/html/solutions/index.html